# How to add touch gestures into video view?

Tags: android, gestures, android-videoview

I am trying to add touch gestures into a video view, but **I have no idea how to add fast forward and rewind**.
I added other controls except these two.
I used `onGestureListener`, but now I think I need to use a drag listener for forwarding, I am not sure.

Here is my code:

```
public class Video extends Activity implements OnGestureListener{

    private GestureDetector gd;

    private VideoView vidView;
    int sec, eventaction;

    long timd, timu;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        String vidAddress = "file:///storage/emmc/Apple - iPhone 5s - The new Touch ID fingerprint identity sensor.mp4";
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
        vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
        vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
        vidView.start();


       //Creating GestureDetector Object
       gd = new GestureDetector(this, this);
       //Assiging value to ImageView Object

       //Setting Default Image of the ImageView

       }

       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
           //Registering TouchEvent with GestureDetector
           return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {
           //Destroying Activity
           finish();
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onDown(MotionEvent arg0) {
           return false;
       }

      @Override
       public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
       //Defining Sensitivity
       float sensitivity = 50;
       //Swipe Up Check
       if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > sensitivity){
       //Setting Image Resource to Up_Arrow on Swipe Up

       return true;
       }
       //Swipe Down Check
       if(e2.getY() - e1.getY() > sensitivity){
       //Setting Image Resource to Down_Arrow on Swipe Down

       return true;
       }
       //Swipe Left Check
       if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > sensitivity) {
       //Setting Image Resource to Left_Arrow on Swipe Left
           vidView.pause();
            sec=vidView.getCurrentPosition();
            vidView.seekTo(1000+sec);
            vidView.start();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "swipe left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       return true;
       }
       //Swipe Right Check
     if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > sensitivity) {

       //Setting Image Resource to Right_Arrow on Swipe Right

                //if(e1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    //while(e2.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    vidView.pause();
                    sec=vidView.getCurrentPosition();
                    vidView.seekTo(1000+sec);
                    vidView.start();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "swipe right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       return true;
       } else {
       //If some error occurrs, setting again to Default_Image (Actually it will never happen in this case)

       return true;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent arg0) { }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent arg0, MotionEvent arg1, float arg2, float arg3) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent arg0) {
        if(vidView.isPlaying()) {
          vidView.pause();
      }
      else {
          vidView.start();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent arg0) {
        return false;
    }
```